# Is it safe to use locals() as a means of passing parameters to a SQL query?

Tags: python, python-db-api

I have code similar to the following:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2})
```

Is there any reason I should use the dictionary literal to pass the parameters, rather than simply doing this:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:var1, :var2)", locals())
```

This feels simpler and more maintainable, but I can't shake the feeling that there is some kind of security smell going on here.

Comment: If the query is hardcoded, this isn't so bad. You aren't passing anything not named in the query over-the-wire, unless your DBAPI library is really horrific.

Comment: There is a risk that unwanted data may get in your database using this. Using a dictionary you have more control about what exactly gets inserted. For you this might be clear, but as soon as someone else will start working with your code, unexpected bad things might happen.

Comment: ...actually, I *have* seen some pretty awful DBAPI libraries; you might want to actually audit with wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a security issue (unless you don't clean the query string itself).

It's a maintenance issue:

1. You're passing "everything", so a poorly written query (i.e., a typo on your part) might pick up an unintended value out of locals(). By being more explicit, it's you're more likely to catch this.
2. You're not telling the "future programmers" exactly what you're using for your query, so someone might alter the value of the parameter prior to your SQL call, resulting in unintended behavior.

In a short query (such as your example) using `locals()` isn't such a tragedy. Using a more complicated query such as (something I grab out of my nearest emacs buffer):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
include_parents(a_id, parent_id, uid, distance) AS ( 
  SELECT accounts.a_id, 
         CASE WHEN admin_can_add THEN NULL
         ELSE accounts.parent_id END AS parent_id, 
         uid, 0 AS distance 
    FROM accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN account_users
         ON (accounts.a_id = account_users.a_id AND admin_can_add)
   WHERE accounts.a_id = $a_id
  UNION ALL 
   SELECT accounts.a_id,
          CASE WHEN admin_can_add THEN NULL
          ELSE accounts.parent_id END as parent_id, 
          account_users.uid, distance + 1 as distance 
     FROM accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN account_users 
          ON (accounts.a_id = account_users.a_id AND admin_can_add), 
          include_parents 
    WHERE accounts.a_id = include_parents.parent_id 
 ) 
SELECT a_id, uid, distance from include_parents 
       WHERE uid IS NOT NULL
```

In such a case, passing `{'a_id': 14}` makes it more clear the full extent of **what** I'm passing rather than `locals()`. Plus, if if my query bombs out looking for another parameter which I forgot to pass (maybe because I slightly altered this query from another usage) it will force me to look more closely at my code. If I passed `locals()`, the query may "succeed" in a way I didn't intend.

Comment: 1. Isn't it just as likely that I'll make typos through having to type out my field list three times? 2. What could be clearer than writing the fields that I'm using in the query, in the query?

Comment: @jl6, do you expect IDEs, or tools like pylint or pychecker, to be able to parse your SQL query string and tell where your variables are used? Those tools are going to behave considerably better when usage is explicit.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using Python 3.6 you can use [f-string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:{var1}, :{var2})")
```

Comment: This is tailor made to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Data must **only ever** be passed out-of-band from code itself. Oblig: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I'm not an expert but I thought the general rule was to let the sql library do the formatting, since it takes care to escape variables correctly and safely

Comment: There are databases that do this poorly (*ahem*MySQL*ahem*), but the general rule is to keep code and data out-of-band from each other, so with a well-designed wire protocol your SQL library isn't even doing *formatting*, but passing multiple distinct fields (one for the SQL itself with placeholders for data, and another per datum) over-the-wire separately.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How is this at all different than his question about using locals()?

Comment: @DanGayle, because in the original question, the data was being passed in a **completely separate argument to the `execute()` call** in both the example that *did* use `locals()` and the one that didn't, thus keeping it out-of-band (and avoiding SQL injection attacks thereby) in either case.

Comment: What does it mean to keep it "out of band"? Do you have a reference I can learn from?